# Trying to control ISQL/Perform DISPLAYONLY field tags when aborting actions?

Tags: informix

ISQL 7.3 Perform:

In my Perform screen I have:

```
dsptag1 = DISPLAYONLY TYPE SMALLINT;
dsptag2 = DISPLAYONLY TYPE DECIMAL;
lastpdate = transaction.last_pymt_date; [DATE]
inttab1   = interest.int_rate1; [DEC(5,2) {from lookup table}]

AFTER QUERY DISPLAY OF transaction
LET dsptag1 = TODAY - lastpdate
LET dsptag2 = inttab1 * dsptag1
[...]
```

After I have located the desired row, I proceed to (U)pdate it with an interest pymt by entering the number of months customer is going to pay, but decide to abort (CTRL-C) the action.  Unfortunately,  the `dsptag1` and `dsptag2` values weren't restored to what AFTER QUERY DISPLAY told it to display, as well as other displayonly tags.  However table-cols properly revert to their pre-update values!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a bug indeed.  Please report it to IBM Technical Support.

If you aren't on the latest version of ISQL (which is 7.50.xC4, so you are not since you say 7.3 - which is imprecise since 7.30.xC1 was released years before 7.32.xC1, but unambiguously not ISQL 7.50), it is likely that you will be requested to upgrade to that.  If the problem persists in the updated version, then you will get to create a bug, and in due course a fix will be released to you.